# Hyperledger Fabric's Idemix usage

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I want to try the idemix feature introduced by Fabric 1.3 version. based on the [repo](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk). I did some changes in order to support idemix. But when I run `java -cp blockchain-client.jar org.example.chaincode.invocation.InvokeChaincode`
,btw, I omitted the step 5 for Register and enroll users, I came across

```
2019-10-18 03:20:10.312 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 049 channel [mychannel]: creator certificate is not valid: Failed verifing with opts [&{<nil> <nil> [] [{1 [111 114 103 49]} {2 1} {0 <nil>} {0 <nil>}] 3 [] 0 0xc00000fab8 0}]: signature invalid: APrime and ABar don't have the expected structure
2019-10-18 03:20:10.312 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04a unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.22.0.1:33960 error="access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [idemixMSPID1]" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=82.6484ms` from peer container.
```

I set up a fabric network with minimal components. Two organizations, each has two peers and a CA. The demo is from [repo](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk). The demo's network with no idemix feature supported works well. When I add idemix section to configtx.yaml, regenerate crypto material, create a channel, etc. And the network finally is up. All containers are work well. But I interact with fab car chaincode using java-sdk, the above error info was thrown.

The following are from configtx.yaml file(just show key parts here):

Organizations:

```
- &OrdererOrg

    Name: OrdererOrg

    ID: OrdererMSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

- &Org1
    Name: Org1MSP
    ID: Org1MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

- &Org2
    Name: Org2MSP

    ID: Org2MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
- &Org1Idemix
    Name: idemixMSP1

    ID: idemixMSPID1

    msptype: idemix
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com

- &Org2Idemix
    Name: idemixMSP2

    ID: idemixMSPID2

    msptype: idemix
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com
```

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_3: true

```
Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V1_1: true

Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V1_3: true
    #V1_2: false
    #V1_1: false
```

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"

```
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities
```

Profiles:
    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org1Idemix
                    - *Org2Idemix
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org1Idemix
                - *Org2Idemix
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

The code I add in InvokeChaincode.java before creating channel client as follows:

```
 // org/example/chaincode/invocation.java
 UserContext normalUserContext = new UserContext();
String name = "user"+System.currentTimeMillis();
normalUserContext.setName(name);
normalUserContext.setAffiliation(Config.ORG1);
normalUserContext.setMspId(Config.ORG3_IDEMIX_MSP);
String enrollmentSecret = caClient.registerUser(name, Config.ORG1);
normalUserContext = caClient.idemixEnrollUser(normalUserContext, enrollmentSecret,normalUserContext.getMspId());


FabricClient fabClient = new FabricClient(normalUserContext);
```

The configuration file added code:

```
// org/example/config/Config.java
 public static final String ORG3 = "org3";
 public static final String ORG3_IDEMIX_MSP = "idemixMSPID1";
```

And docker-composer.yaml file remains unchanged.
All the images used are 1.4.1

I expect the endorser peer able to verify tx proposal from client with idemix enabled. But now the peer side report `2019-10-18 03:20:10.312 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 049 channel [mychannel]: creator certificate is not valid: Failed verifing with opts [&{<nil> <nil> [] [{1 [111 114 103 49]} {2 1} {0 <nil>} {0 <nil>}] 3 [] 0 0xc00000fab8 0}]: signature invalid: APrime and ABar don't have the expected structure
2019-10-18 03:20:10.312 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04a unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.22.0.1:33960 error="access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [idemixMSPID1]" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=82.6484ms`

I don't know why. I guess that if a peer does not support idemix tx verification. Are there some switches not open on peers?  Help. Any replies will be thankful.